# How to connect to internet through VM's internet connection?

Tags: 11.10, windows-7, vmware, windows-xp, internet-connection

I am new to Ubuntu. I have a wimax connection(UH-235). I connect the device through USB. **The connection must be DHCP**(assigned by the service provider). Problem is, the driver+connection manager software is only available for Windows and the source are closed. 
So I couldn't find any way to connect to internet from Ubuntu. So I setup Windows-7 in vmware-workstation and now I can connect to internet from my guest PC(Windows-7). Is there any possible way to share the connection of guest-Windows7 internet connection to my host (Ubuntu)??

Comment: Get a loopback ethernet connector, use bridged networking, and set up ICS on the windows vm.  I don't have a copy of vmware, so I can't post a detailed walkthrough, but those are the broad strokes.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. What is loopback ethernet connector??

Comment: this is a loopback ethernet connector: http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos10.0/information-products/topic-collections/nog-interfaces/fe-ge-loopback-creating.html#id-11866686

Comment: @aking1012 : I couldn't able to collect any loopback ethernet connector. Is there any other way you know?

Comment: not that i'm aware of

Comment: O, ok. :-( hope there is some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Following Configuration worked for me to communicate with virtual guests installed in Virtual Box using an Ethernet loop-back plug (http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos10.0/information-products/topic-collections/nog-interfaces/fe-ge-loopback-creating.html#id-11866686).

First Edit /etc/network/interfaces and add following lines to that

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.10
        network 192.168.0.0
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.0.255
        gateway 192.168.0.1
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_fd 9
        bridge_hello 2
        bridge_maxage 12
        bridge_stp off

restart network /etc/init.d/networking restart

it seems STP is on in ubuntu bydefault thats the reason Loopback plug not working without the configuration.

Comment: Sorry I tried but didn't work for me. :(